# how to install perl XML::XPath on Windows?

Tags: xml, perl, xpath

Been running in Google'ish circles trying to install XML::XPath on windows.
Windows 10, Perl 5.4 (where perl = /usr/bin/perl).

I am running Strawberry perl.
"cpan install XML::XPath" fails,

```
> cpan install XML::XPath
Can't find E:\Plang\Strawberry_Perl\perl\bin\cpan.bat on PATH, '.' not in PATH.
```

Manual download of xml-xpath-1.44, then unpacking, and run makefile, fails:

> perl Makefile.PL

```
Expat must be installed prior to building XML::Parser and I can't find
it in the standard library directories. Install 'expat-devel'...
```

So I went to the site: http://sourceforge.net/projects/expat/ and downloaded and ran:

```
expat-win32bin-2.2.9.exe
```

and ran it, and then ran the recommended revised Makefile command:

```
perl Makefile.PL EXPATLIBPATH=e:/plang/expat/lib EXPATINCPATH=e:/plang/expat/include
```

but xml-parser Makefile still fails in the same way.

### Seems like it should be easier than this; maybe I am missing something?

(Strawberry perl installed from their site latest .msi file = 5.30.)
C:\Users\guthrie>which cpan
/e/Plang/Strawberry_Perl/perl/bin/cpan

### (pip comment; sorry, simultaneously trying this on Python!)

Comment: Which version of Windows? Which version of perl?

Comment: It installs fine on Windows 10 using `cpanm` and [Strawberry Perl](http://strawberryperl.com/) version 5.30.0

Comment: `Can't find E:\Plang\Strawberry_Perl\perl\bin\cpan.bat on PATH` How did you install Strawberry Perl?

Comment: `pip install XML::XPath` : `pip` is used to install Python modules, it can't be used to install a Perl module.

Comment: Please provide the output of `where perl` and `where cpan`.

Comment: Many thanks @Haekon - doing a "which perl" showed that I had another one installed, in ..\Git\usr\bin which was on the search path before Strawberry. Actually several programs install their own local perl.exe, so I moved Strawberry to the to of the %path% list, and it installed fine. Many thanks.

Comment: The Strawberry Perl distribution already includes (i.e. it is installed already) XML::LibXML which is a superior module for handling XML, and happens to have almost the same API. I would definitely recommend using XML::LibXML in preference to XML::XPath for new code, and port existing code should be trivial.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Strawberry Perl's `cpan.bat` uses the first `perl` in the path. You are using an MSYS build of Perl rather than the Strawberry Perl build for which you want to install the module.

**Solution 1**

Move Strawberry Perl earlier in the PATH.

**Solution 2**

Explicitly specify which `perl` you want to use when executing `cpan`.

```
E:\Plang\Strawberry_Perl\perl\bin\perl  E:\Plang\Strawberry_Perl\perl\bin\cpan XML::XPath
```

**Solution 3**

Explicitly specify which `perl` you want to use, and avoid the `cpan` script in favour of using the underlying module directly.

```
E:\Plang\Strawberry_Perl\perl\bin\perl -MCPAN -e"CPAN::Shell->install(@ARGV)" XML::XPath
```

---

You are likely to run into further problems if you use the second and third solution, so I'd go with the first. It doesn't need to be a permanent change. In fact, you can simply changes the PATH in the console that will be used to install the module.

Comment: Note that I'd use XML::LibXML before XML::XPath.

Comment: Note that since Strawberry installs at the tail of %path%, it is likely that as in my case others would catch "perl" first. It would be good for them to check this and/or warn on installation. In my case, a simple previous git install had its own local perl, and voila!