# perl cpan installation conflicts with GIT Perl cpan installation how can I correct?

Tags: perl, installation, cpan

I'm new to perl, but, I'm just trying to install it on my windows 10 machine, because, I need to use a NAGIOS plugin named check_logfiles.  A perl script/app.

while I am installing Strawberry Perl, I need additional Modules.  I invoked CPAN to install more modules and it fails because it finds the GIT Perl CPAN.

how ( can I ) can Perl be installed and this Perl installation is selected instead of the GIT perl?  I don't know if I can de-install GIT's Perl ?

```
ERROR
Trying with
    /c/bin/wget.EXE -O "/c/Users/212555427/.cpan/sources/authors/01mailrc.txt.gz.tmp7712"
to get
    http://www.cpan.org/authors/01mailrc.txt.gz
--14:42:06--  http://www.cpan.org/authors/01mailrc.txt.gz
           => `C:/Users/212555427/.cpan/sources/authors/01mailrc.txt.gz.tmp7712'
Resolving www.cpan.org... failed: Host not found.
```

This /c/Users/212555427/.cpan is the GIT installation

I install Strawberry Perl under default C:\Strawberry

```
$ which perl
/usr/bin/perl

$ where perl
C:\Strawberry\perl\bin\perl.exe
C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\perl.exe


$ where cpan
C:\Strawberry\perl\bin\cpan
C:\Strawberry\perl\bin\cpan.bat
C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\core_perl\cpan

$ cpan Date::Manip.pm
WARNING: your version of App::Cpan is 1.63_01 while we would expect at least 1.64 at /c/Strawberry/perl/bin/cpan line 11.
Loading internal null logger. Install Log::Log4perl for logging messages
Fetching with LWP:
http://www.cpan.org/authors/01mailrc.txt.gz
LWP failed with code[500] message[Can't connect to www.cpan.org:80]

Trying with
    /c/bin/wget.EXE -O "/c/Users/212555427/.cpan/sources/authors/01mailrc.txt.gz.tmp22892"
to get
    http://www.cpan.org/authors/01mailrc.txt.gz
```

thank you - please let me know if I need to provide anything else to resolve issue.

Comment: What does `cpan -v` output? and `perl --version` ?

Comment: `$ which perl \\  /usr/bin/perl` : Is this correct? In my CMD prompt there is no command `which`

Comment: [Relevant](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63198776/589924)

Comment: ahh, interesting - I have bash for windows installed, I open a bash window.  so I am looking at 2 different shells.  but why would I get 2 different things?   Please see I added to the bottom of question.